# Generating numbering by conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to generate numbering as shown in the table below. Column A defines the condition for generating numbering in column B. So the numbering starts with 10, step is 10 and it ends when the number in the column A changes.

What would be the best way to solve this? IF conditioning or VBA?

```
A   B
789 10
789 20
789 30
789 40
789 50
789 60
789 70
789 80
789 90
564 10
564 20
564 30
564 40
564 50
564 60
564 70
564 80
236 10
236 20
236 30
236 40
236 50
236 60
751 10
751 20
751 30
751 40
751 50
751 60
751 70
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write

- in B1 `=10`
- in B2 formula `=IF(A2=A1,B1+10,10)` and drag it down

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly until it comes to a change in values in column A. It just keeps on adding 10 to the previous values in column B.

Comment: works as expected for me..see my updated answer (and check formula that you're using)

Comment: be sure you are not using `$` sign in formula (absolute references)